# How to send data from Livewire component to a controller?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a very basic Livewire component. I know, there is a `wire:click`, but I simplified it very much, to give you something by hand. In my real app, there is a calendar component and when you click on an event, it fires the `emit()` and sends data from the ui to the Livewire component, where it get's modified.

My question is: How can post this data from the Livewire component to the `foo.store` route?

**app/Http/Livewire/Foo.php:**

```php
class Foo extends Component
{
    public $foo;

    protected $listeners = [
         'store' => 'store'
    ];

    public function render()
    {
         return view('livewire.foo');
    }

    public function store($data)
    {
         $payload = $this->do_complex_math_on_data($data);
         // ❓ post payload to FooController's store() function - HOW?
    }

    private function do_complex_math_on_data($data)
    {
         return 1+1;
    }
}
```

**resources/views/livewire/foo.blade.php:**

```php
<div>
   <button>Click me!</button>
</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function() {
        document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click' () => {
            Livewire.emit('store', data.coming.from.ui);
        });    
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You have a Livewire `Foo` `Component` and a standard `FooController`?

Comment: yes, I do, of course

Comment: Not sure why you say _of course_, I think you're missing the entire point of Livewire. Just perform your `store` functionality in the `Foo` `Component`.

Comment: And that is what I want to avoid, as the `FooController` has the store function, that covers the foo storage. Many views have forms to post to this endpoint, so should the Livewire component.

Comment: Extract the shared functionality to a service class, then use the [Service Container & Dependency Injection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/container) to inject that service class into every `Controller` or `Component` that requires the ability to store `Foo` objects.

Comment: So no way to just use something simple like `post($data, foo.store)`?

Comment: You could use the [HTTP Client](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client) but a service class would be the better approach. Up to you though, your project.

Comment: I tried the Service Container and it is working for me. Thank you, great tipp!

Answer (score 0):

From your prospect of the controller, as Peppermintology stated, there are two types of controller, one is a standard **Laravel** controller and the second is a **Livewire** component controller, from there you have to understand that the livewire controller lifecycle is detached from Laravel. it is working as a waterfall, you can inject data from the Laravel controller to the Livewire component but from Livewire to Laravel standard component you can't, though you can pass data between the livewire ecosystem like from parent component to child or vice-versa

Like below

```
$this->emitUp('postAdded');
```

or

```
<button wire:click="$emitUp('postAdded')">
```

you can read more about nesting components in livewire [Nesting component](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/nesting-components), and also about event [Events](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events)